# Regex matching the end of a line correctly

Tags: python, regex

I'm looking for a way to `re.sub` lines ending with `\n` and `\r\n` while preserving the line ending.

```
import re
data = "Foo\r\nFoo\nFoo"
regex = r"^Foo$"
re.sub(regex, "Bar", data, flags=re.MULTILINE)
```

leaves me with

```
Foo\r\nBar\nBar
```

When using the regex `^Foo(\r)?$` to check for an optional `\r`, I'll end up with

```
Bar\nBar\nBar
```

Any ideas?

**Edit**: Expected result

```
Bar\r\nBar\nBar
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [positive lookahead assertion](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/regex.html#lookahead-assertions)

```
import re
data = "Foo\r\nFoo\nFoo"
regex = r"^Foo(?=\r?\n?$)"
re.sub(regex, "Bar", data, flags=re.MULTILINE)
```

Output :

```
'Bar\r\nBar\nBar'
```

---

[Regex explanation here.](https://regex101.com/r/oL1nU7/1)

[image: Regular expression visualization]

Answer (score 1):

Make the `\r` and `\n` optional with `?`, and specify them as a capture group so you can refer to them in the callback function for the replacement:

```
>>> re.sub('^Foo(\r?\n?)$', r'Bar\1', 'Foo\r\nFoo\nFoo', flags=re.MULTILINE)
'Bar\r\nBar\nBar'
```

This will match lines ending in `\r`, `\n`, or `\r\n`, and lines without a linefeed at all.